# Usage of the 's

Tags: grammaticality, apostrophe

Should I use `Video options` or `Video's options` when referring to a few video properties that can be edited?

Comment: It's "Video options", but I'm afraid I can't explain why. Stand by for better answers...

Comment: You only need the `-'s` when it's a definite person: _Bill's options, Your options,_ but for a non-specific indefinite like _User_, either _User's Options_ or _User Options_ may be used. Otherwise noun compounding like _video options_ is the only real alternative, unless you want to use a Romance genitive like _Options of Platinum-Level Users' Video,_ which comes in handy for heavy noun phrases like _Platinum-Level User_.

Answer (score 0):

Properties that are associated with videos are called

> video options
>   *Among the video options that can be changed for viewing are...*

since you are referring to videos in general.

If you are referring to a specific video you might use

> The *video's options* allow you to specify what aspect ratio you would like to use.